# Make tab active in Bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a second tab active in Bootstrap, when i set the `class="active"` on the second `li` it shows active but shows the content of the first tab. I'm using `PHP` to set active tab, with two variables `$login_tab` and `$signup_tab`

```
$login_tab = 'class="active"';
$signup_tab = '';
if (isset($_GET['joined']) && $_GET['joined'] === 'true'){
$login_tab = '';
$signup_tab = 'class="active"';
}
```

and my list

```
<li role="presentation" <?php echo $login_tab; ?>><a href="#user-sign-in" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
<li role="presentation"  <?php echo $signup_tab; ?>><a href="#user-sign-up" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Sign-up</a></li>
```

I have tried with `jQuery` and still doesn't work.

```
$('#sign-up-tabs li.active').tab('show');
```

How can I make a tab active based on the values of the two variables?

Comment: can you do a console.log of : $('#sign-up-tabs li.active') ? do you really have a #sign-up-tabs node above your li ( i think but just in case)

Comment: Yes i do, i have solded it using `hash`.

Answer (score 0):

You also must add the class active to the tabpanel inside the tab-content.

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="user-sign-in">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="user-sign-up">...</div>
</div>
```